# Appcode building iOS universal framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa, appcode

I decided to use the Appcode for 30days. (trial)
I might buy this product because of powerful features.
However, I have a question about building universal framework.
Precisely, the Run script for the build phases.
In Xcode, I could add the Run scripts at the Build Settings, lipo to make it to universal framework.
But I cannot find it in Appcode.
I know the Appcode is not popular yet, but I hope there's someone else who struggles to use this new IDE.

Conclusion:
1. Is there any ways to add my Run scripts in the projects?
2. If not, how can I build frameworks as universal?
Thanks

Comment: may be this link helpful to you :http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: Also, you can use this repo: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Precisely, the Run script for the build phases. In Xcode, I could add
>   the Run scripts at the Build Settings, lipo to make it to universal
>   framework. But I cannot find it in Appcode.

In AppCode you can do it by navigating to **Run -> Edit configurations**. Then select target on the left. On the right side you will be able to see "Before launch window" and a plus button at the bottom. By pressing it you can add external tool run phase (which is the same with **Run script** phase in Xcode). [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMDRP.png)